# Is there a way to use different environment profiles for development and production setting for Cordova app based on Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, cordova, gruntjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Say like we have in Spring Framework a lot of variations to set compile/run/test time environment, and use it to bind a different properties files with settings.
It is made for us not to change anything except this one environment/profile variable to be able to have proper settings for app.

More particularly:

I have two files: settings.dev.js and settings.prod.js

**settings.prod.js:**

```
var API_PATH = "http://example.com/api"
var OTHER_INPORTANT_SETTINGS = {....}
```

**settings.dev.js:**

```
var API_PATH = "http://localhost.com/api"
var OTHER_INPORTANT_SETTINGS = {....}
```

and an Ionic Framework app where services are using this settings. E.g.

```
me: $resource(API_PATH + '/my/profile', {}, {...}
```

And so on in many services and controllers and maybe directives...

Is there some way to use

- settings.dev.js while in development and
- settings.prod.js for deployment a release app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just develop a solution for the issue.

1. Create a grunt task (or the equivalent build tools) to copy the `settings.<env>.js` file to `settings.js` file.

   ```
   copy: {
     dev: {
       src: 'settings.dev.js',
       dest: 'settings.js'
     },
     prod: {
       src: 'settings.prod.js',
       dest: 'settings.js'
     }
   },

   grunt.registerTask('dev', [
     'copy:development'
   ]);


   grunt.registerTask('prod', [
     'copy:prod'
   ]);
   ```
2. Include `settings.js` in your html or js file.
3. Add `settings.js` to your `.gitignore` file so that your environment specific file won't affect others.

Answer (score 3):

As one of the approaches you can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['processhtml:dev']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['processhtml:prod', ...]);
```

In html:

```
<!-- build:remove:dev -->
<script src="/your/path/settings.prod.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->

<!-- build:remove:prod -->
<script src="/your/path/settings.dev.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->
```

It means that `<script src="/your/path/settings.prod.js"></script>` will be removed for `dev`, and `<script src="/your/path/settings.dev.js"></script>` will be removed for `prod`.

Now to build a production environment use `grunt` command, and to build a development env. use `grunt dev`.

And one more thing, you can use [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) to automate dev builds:

```
watch: {
    html: {
        files: ['www/*.html'],
        tasks: ['dev']
    }
}
```

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: is Grunt only accepting two environments (dev and prod) . Can I use new environment like 'local','qa','stage' ?

Comment: yes you can, because here the environment name is simply the task name. And the [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml) module I use to filter the script tags here just accepts target-name after the colon to be anything you write.


The approach I use here is quite outdated and not so cool. I'd reccomended to take a look at some module bundlers like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)


If you preffer to stick with grunt then @edmond-chui 's copy approach is much better IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I used this package and it works great:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-config

As long as you have a task that runs before your minify/browserify/etc, you can have it included into your single compiled JS file.

Answer (score 0):

For loading config files  you can just ad script tag with the script URL in the HTML.

```
<script src="/your/path/settings.prod.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="/your/path/settings.dev.js"></script>
```

Then you can defined variables as usual.

Comment: I am actually loading config files such way. But I want to be able to load different files depending on profile, like dev for dev, prod for production.

And how does it help me to be able to load different script depending on what am i doing, developing or producing?

Comment: You can actually run script that rewrites filename to 'prod' before deployment, and that will rewrite filename back to 'dev' after deployment.

Comment: Well, thank you. Can I get the example somewhere? With Spring it is much more easy. I thought there could b some easy tool for cordova or ionic too.